# How to prove surjectivity of the map $S*G\to End_{S^G}(S)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ be a finite dimensional vector space, $G$ be a finite subgroup of $SL(V)$, then $G$ has a natural action on $S=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. It is known that $S*G$ (the skew group ring) is isomorphic to the endomorphism ring $End_{S^G}(S)$. I am trying to prove this fact and here are my work:

Construct a map $\Phi:S*G\to End_{S^G}(S)$ as follows: for $F\in S$, $\Phi(s,g)(F)=s\cdot g(F)$. Note that $End_{S}(S)\subset End_{S^G}(S)$ and the action $g\in End_{S^G}(S)$. It is easy to verify that this gives a ring homomorphism and is in fact injective.

> My question: How do we prove surjectivity of this map?

Any help is greatly appreciated!